# Random Internal Server Error

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, apache-2.4, php7, cgi

We are receiving random internal server errors on one of our website.

These internal server errors can sometimes appear only on some users but other users are not receiving it (at the very same time) and vice versa.

The said internal server errors goes away after several page refresh.

I have confirmed that this is not a script issue. I have tested it by using a `test.php` that only `echo`es a test string. Once an internal server error is thrown, even the said `test.php` throws the same error for a couple of minutes and starts working again after several page refresh.

`error logs` does not contain anything of relevance with the said error. I have confirmed that error logs are working by intentionally accessing a php script that will throw a fatal error and warning. Both thrown error and warning is logged correctly.

I have also consulted with our hosting which is `ipower` and they have confirmed that both `.htaccess` and our `php.ini` is correct. They even said that `PHP` is properly installed on our server and should start working properly. As of the moment, we have an open ticket with regards to this and they are *still* *trying* to investigate.

If I may add, we are using `opencart 3.0.3.7` and the exact clone of our website is working just fine on one of our test domains and other server on the said hosting company.

Are there any other possible causes for the said error to emerge? The answer may seem to be *opinionated* but please don't hesitate to downvote if necessary and **please** if possible post a comment on what is/are your thought(s) with regards to this *hard to pinpoint oddity*

Comment: Start with logs. Identify one log line corresponding to an instance of the unexpected return code, and look around whether it happens in conjunction with high number of requests, slow responses or large responses.

Comment: @anx thanks for your comment, however CGI error logs are empty. I'm also pretty sure that traffic is low. I've also tested and able to reproduce the error on our *awkward* business hours such as 6am etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the error is random and only seems to occur on that one host, it sounds like a problem with the host's Apache, PHP, or OS. I suggest moving the application to a different host.

No downvote needed :)